# Django, How to get random posts list result?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**CODE: views.py  (I used django-rest-framework)**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self) :
        elasped_minutes_after = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=600)
        self.list_after = Post.objects.filter(created_date__gte = elasped_minutes_after).order_by("?")          
        return self.list_after
```

**Question :**

What i want to know is that If `self.list_after` was longer or equal 33, for example `self.list_after` has 50 posts, How to show 33 posts for random and
if length of `self.list_after` was shorter than 33, For example, `self.list_after` has 20 posts, How to show 20 posts all.

Would you help me?

Comment: did you try `.order_by("?") [:33]` ?

Comment: Oh, good thank you. @Marat

Comment: @Marat I would suggest posting you comment as answer. Or mark this post as duplicate if think it is such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it an official answer, [use slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets):

```
...
return self.list_after[:33]
```

Note that the result is still a queryset, not a list